# AngularJS broke Layout charset on Asp.Net 5 MVC6 _Layout

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, character-encoding, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to learn AngularJS on MVC6. Everything works OK but angular broke something about utf-8 charset or etc. The page (View) that I use angular.min.js doesn't show my Turkish characters properly. I also included locale js file.

```
<script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular-locale_tr-tr/angular-locale_tr-tr.min.js"></script>
```

But nothing changed. I still see this:

> Ç,Ş,ı,İ   as   ��

I don't know is this about utf-8 encoding or anything else but other pages that I didn't include angular shows these characters properly.

What should I do? What is the exact problem?

EDIT:
This is happening with only layouts' or other text.

For example, this code block shows same characters properly:

```
<tr ng-repeat="city in vm.cities">
  <td>
    {{city.cityName}} // 
 //cityName shows even it is İstanbul not �stanbul as in the site title
  </td>     
</tr>
```